# JasperReports export to xlsx, not xls

Tags: java, jasper-reports, xls, xlsx

I can't find how to export a file in .xlsx in JasperReports 4.1.1. 
The class:

```
JRXlsExporter
```

has not a Xlsx equivalent. And i can't find a parameter to set the output format from xls to xlsx.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRXlsxExporter.html

Comment: @Alex You should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [*JRXlsxExporter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRXlsxExporter.html) class should be used for exporting at ***XLSX*** format.

#### Sample of using exporter with JasperReports prior 5.5.2 version

Till *JasperReports 5.5.1* this code can be used for generating report at *xlsx* format:

```
JRMapArrayDataSource dataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(data);

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportJRXMLSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);

JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFileName);

exporter.exportReport();
```

Since *5.5.2* version of library the *JRAbstractExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter, Object)* method is deprecated.

#### Sample of using exporter with modern JasperReports versions

In this example I used *JRS 6.4.1* version:

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
try (InputStream inputStream = JRLoader.getResourceInputStream(jrxmlFilePath)) {
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream));
}
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
configuration.setIgnoreGraphics(false);

File outputFile = new File("output.xlsx");
try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    Exporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(byteArrayOutputStream));
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
}
```

Instead of using *JRExporter.setParameter* method we have to use implementation of [*XlsReportConfiguration*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/XlsReportConfiguration.html) interface. In example above I used *SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration* implementation of *XlsReportConfiguration* for defining settings specific to *JRXlsxExporter* exporter.

---

#### More information

- [Advanced Excel Features](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures)
- [Batch Export Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html#batchexport)

Comment: Do we need to update the version to the higher one? I am using `jasperreports-3.7.6`

Comment: @tailorBird The version 3.7.0 contains this class. The last version of *JR* is 5.5.1

Comment: Thanks @Alex K. Actually I have asked a question [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497343/jrxlsexporter-invalid-row-number-65536-outside-allowable-range) regarding this. I found an answer here. Will try this.

Comment: 5 years later, the JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT has been deprecated, I have add non deprecated solution.

Comment: setParameter() is deprecated since version 5.6. Look at the post below

Comment: @DanBrandt Yes, this example was posted 7 years ago :) I added actual example, thanks

Answer (score 19):

> This answer is to help users with **JASPER REPORT VERSION >5.6** (latest versions), hence remove the deprecated code.

In later version >5.6 the `JRXlsxExporter.setParameter(..)` has been `deprecated`.

You should use

```
JRMapArrayDataSource dataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(data);

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportJRXMLSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);

JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
File outputFile = new File("excelTest.xlsx");
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration(); 
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);//Set configuration as you like it!!
configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is put the format in the request path, like this:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/ActivityReport.xlsx", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public ModelAndView generateActivityReportXLS( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {


    List<ActivityDisplay> list = activityManager.listActivities();

    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
    parameterMap.put( "datasource", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( list ) );
    return new ModelAndView( "activitiesXLSView", parameterMap );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JRXlsExporter is available in in JasperReports 4.5 and later versions.