# How to create excel 2007+ (XLSX) file format using Jasper

Tags: excel, reporting, jasper-reports, excel-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JasperReports export to xlsx, not xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245009/jasperreports-export-to-xlsx-not-xls)

My current project required to produce huge data ( mostly over 100k row) in excel report.

Since Excel 2003 format (*.xls) only support 64k row therefore i need excel 2007+ (*xlsx) because it can handle up to 1 million row.

Could anyone tell me how to create / configure these report using jasper report?(create *xlsx report instead *xls report)

Comment: Do yon need java API solution?

Comment: You can read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245009/jasperreports-export-to-xlsx-not-xls/7990811#7990811