# How to set Jasper to use XSSF?

Tags: jasper-reports, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

In a existing system already use jasper 5.0 and as I know it use poi **HSSF** to generate xls data, but now as the application grow up, the report have a problem with a big count transaction to generate.

I have search for the solution and found POI with **XSSF**. Because jasper use POI HSSF too, I thinking about to use XSSF inside of JASPER.

Is that possible? and how I could do that? I need to use jasper because it's not possible for now to change the existing app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export jrxml generating **ooxml** `XSSF`, excel file **xlxs**

Use the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter`

Example:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, paramMap, connection); //Example of how to get the jasper print

JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
File outputFile = new File("excelTest.xlsx");
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration(); 
configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false); //Set configuration as you like it!!
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Naturally you need related libraries (poi-ooxml.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas.jar, xmlbeans.jar) in your classpath, they are present in the distribution of jasper report.

The `JRXlsxExporter` is available since version 4.5 this is the [jasper report 5.5.0 API](http://javadox.com/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.5.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRXlsxExporter.html). In version 4 parameters where set instead of properties please see [jasperreports-export-to-xlsx-not-xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245009/jasperreports-export-to-xlsx-not-xls)